# Summary of changes field does not set uppercase for first character

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, edit-summary

When editing a question in the iOS app, the "Summary of changes " field does not set the shift button on the iOS keyboard automatically, and so the first letter is not automatically upper case.

There are fields which do this, although I can not offhand think of a concrete example.

I know that the web page version does not offer this functionality, but as it is possible to do this in an app, would this not be a good idea, in order to reduce the number of key presses and to maintain/provide a tidy change summary?

> [image: screenshot of edit page]

Another example, without the uppercase key set

> [image: Screenshot of edit page]

With the uppercase key set

> [image: Screenshot of edit page it uppercase key set]

- App version 1.6.4
- iOS 10.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.5.3

The property just wasn't set.

Comment: That was suspiciously fast.

Comment: @JasonC Bug was first on the list *chronologically*, and https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6U7o.png